# How to use mini opera in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mobile, browser, opera-mini

In my project, I need to take a webshot of any website to display how it looks like when visible in opera mini(in mobile). Application is desktop based and I don't want to use opera for desktop since website view will be different in opera mini and opera for desktop and this difference is how website is rendered on mini opera.

My question is, Is there any way to embed opera mini in C# desktop application.
Any other mobile browser is also acceptable(except webkit).

thanx

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer lies in the Opera Mobile Emulator. This is essentially a version of Opera Mini that runs on the desktop. It can be configured to run in various SmartPhone screen sizes and features so it should give you what you need.  You can get it free from here http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/

Comment: How can I access emulator in my .net app?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [simulator for Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mini/) specifically (which is not the [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/)). It is powered by [MicroEmulator](http://www.microemu.org/), a pure Java implementation of Java 2 Micro Edition in Java 2 Standard Edition licensed under LGPL.

You can follow the instructions on the blog post [Using MicroEmulator to run Opera Mini](http://my.opera.com/ariesptn/blog/2008/11/17/using-microemulator-to-run-opera-mini).

From here you might be able to use the system for targetting the windows of the microEmulator in C#.